# How to return first non empty string value from list of strings(sorted) in java

Tags: java, list, for-loop, java-8

I have list of string values and wants to return first non empty value and this list is sorted. how to achieve this?

```
for( String data:schoolDetails.getStudentdata(){
 // have to get first non empty data 
}
```

any leads would be helpful.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this `List` contain `null` values or are you sure there are only initialized `String`s (like you're sure it's sorted)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the introduction of [`Stream`s](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) in Java 8, we can express this in a functional way:

```
return schoolDetails.getStudentdata().stream()
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(null);
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/ODtkaP)

Since it is not guaranteed that a non-`null` value exists, we return `null` if no non-`null` value exists. Alternatively, we can skip the `orElse(...)`-step and return an [`Optional<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html), signaling that the result might be empty:

```
return schoolDetails.getStudentdata().stream()
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .findFirst();
```

We can furthermore modify what we want to filter by, for example, using [`String::isBlank`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#isBlank()) in addition to [`Objects::nonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#nonNull(java.lang.Object)) and the help of [`Predicate::not`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html#not(java.util.function.Predicate)):

```
return schoolDetails.getStudentdata().stream()
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .filter(Predicate.not(String::isBlank))
    .findFirst();
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/Q4oEev)

Comment: your `Predicate` should be `s -> !s.isBlank()`

Comment: @IQbrod fixed & added ideone demo